# problemas de inicio de ubuntu

Tags: dell

Hola tengo una dell 7559 instale bien todo pero al momento de reiniciar no me entra al sistema almenos que ponga c GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset quiet splash" ayuda

Translation:

I have a Dell 7559 and just installed Ubuntu.
However, Ubuntu does not boot up after the installation.
I have already added the line in the grub file:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset quiet splash"
but it still does not work. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Usted necesita tener `nouveau.modeset=0` en el archivo. Así es como yo arranco Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS en mi Dell Inspiron 7559.

Por lo que la comida de archivo debe tener este aspecto:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = "quiet splash nouveau.modeset = 0"`

A continuación, deberá actualizar GRUB:

`sudo update-grub`

```
Translation:

You need to have `nouveau.modeset=0` in the grub file so that Ubuntu can boot.
After that, update grub by running sudo update-grub.
```

Comment: Looks like you know Spanish. Do you mind translating the question too?

Comment: @edwinksl Thanks for notifying me. I don't know why I did not do that in the first place. :)